# warning exif_read_data(php3KLADx): File not supported in /home/i/public_html/orientation.php on line 5

Tags: php

I get exif to read orientation of upload images.
The problem is in some images I'm getting this error:

> warning exif_read_data(php3KLADx): File not supported in
>   /home/i/public_html/orientation.php on line 5

any ideas how to avoid this?

```
<?php
function exif_orientation($file_tmp) {

$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file_tmp));
$exif = exif_read_data($file_tmp);

if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 8:
            $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
            break;
        case 3:
            $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
            break;
        case 6:
            $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
            break;
    }
    imagejpeg($image, $file_tmp, 90);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could suppress the output of the warning by using:

`@exif_read_data($file_tmp)`

Of course, suppressing warnings is not a good idea, but there doesn't seem to be a way of avoiding this warning: there's no function to test the validity of the EXIF data without trying to read it and getting the warning.

I tried testing with

`exif_imagetype($file_tmp)`

but some valid image types can have readable EXIF data or not. 
PNG is one: I found examples where one file could be read just fine but the other gave the warning.

Comment: Use a try-catch if you expect an error. Do not use @

Comment: But try-catch won't suppress the warning.
In 30 years of coding I have tried to follow best practices (like not suppressing warnings, not using goto, never allowing a case statement to fall though to the next one) but there are use cases for all of these things that occur occasionally.
If I ever break one these prescriptive rules I comment the code to indicate why I did it, so that when some over-zealous, over-qualified programmer comes along and changes it to the 'right' thing I know who to blame when the programs stops working :)

Comment: Came across this today, try catch doesn't work, have to use @

Answer (score 5):

You Should do it Like below :

```
if (!function_exists('imageOrientation'))
{
function imageOrientation(string $directory)
{
    if(file_exists($directory))
    {
        $destination_extension = strtolower(pathinfo($directory, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if(in_array($destination_extension, ["jpg","jpeg"]) && exif_imagetype($directory) === IMAGETYPE_JPEG)
        {
            if(function_exists('exif_read_data'))
            {
                $exif = exif_read_data($directory);
                if(!empty($exif) && isset($exif['Orientation']))
                {
                    $orientation = $exif['Orientation'];
                    switch ($orientation)
                    {
                        case 2:
                            $flip = 1;
                            $deg = 0;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            $flip = 0;
                            $deg = 180;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            $flip = 2;
                            $deg = 0;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            $flip = 2;
                            $deg = -90;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            $flip = 0;
                            $deg = -90;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            $flip = 1;
                            $deg = -90;
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            $flip = 0;
                            $deg = 90;
                            break;
                        default:
                            $flip = 0;
                            $deg = 0;
                    }
                    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($directory);
                    if($deg !== 1 && $img !== null)
                    {
                        if($flip !== 0)
                        {
                            imageflip($img,$flip);
                        }
                        $img = imagerotate($img, $deg, 0);
                        imagejpeg($img, $directory);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why even checking for the filename extension? Why using magic numbers (i.e. `2`) instead of constants (i.e. `IMG_FLIP_BOTH`)? When will `$deg !== 1` ever be FALSE? Why no comments at all?

Comment: What is the key part of your suggestion that supposedly avoids the problem described by the OP?